# IRC chat on pidgin

Tags: irc, pidgin

How do I use IRC chat on pidgin? 
I acquired the Server : irc://irc.freenode.net:6667
and I don't know what to fill in the username?
How do I get a username and password?

[image]

After searching for 30 mins on web I found it Nowhere.

Here's a couple of sites which I read and All of thier contents got above my head as I could not understand a word.

http://www.irchelp.org/irchelp/irctutorial.html

http://www.linuxassist.net/how-to-connect/

It looks like these articles were written just for the experienced users.

Comment: log in with user name anonymous and then follow the information about regisstering your nick in the second url you posted.

Comment: What happens if you type any random characters in the username with no password?

Answer (score 1):

Just connect to that network with no registration the first time with any username and not password, and then I would recommend you to go to http://freenode.net/faq.shtml#nicksetup to register your nickname for the specific IRC server that you are using (freenode), otherwise you are not going to be able to talk at the channels or even join some of them.

By the way I would recommend you that when you join a channel you add a "#" before the name of the channel, otherwise it will tell you that doesn't exist.

Some IRC networks like this one require you to register your nickname so in the case of an attack to their servers they can identify who the attacker is and ban them easily.

Answer (score 0):

Most IRC networks don't require a username or password.

Try leaving them blank.

On IRC, people find you by your nickname, which is a different thing than a username.  If you want to keep the same nickname, see 
https://freenode.net/faq.shtml#contents-userregistration

Comment: The thing is that pidgin is not allowing to leave the username field blank It needs to be filled for the add button to show up

Comment: @Adityaultra I assumed Pidgin would default to your current username.  You should be able to type anything, preferably something short and ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

At least for freenode, this is a sample account:

```
nicholas@dur:~$ 
nicholas@dur:~$ cat .purple/accounts.xml 
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>

<account version='1.0'>
    <account>
        <protocol>prpl-irc</protocol>
        <name>nsaunders@irc.freenode.net</name>
        <password>bklfdjkgoelfjbjfkdkvldfkdkvkgldlcld</password>
        <statuses>
            <status type='available' name='Available' active='true'>
                <attributes/>
            </status>
            <status type='away' name='Away' active='false'>
                <attributes>
                    <attribute id='message' value='I&apos;m not here right now'/>
                </attributes>
            </status>
            <status type='offline' name='Offline' active='false'>
                <attributes/>
            </status>
        </statuses>
        <settings>
            <setting name='auth_plain_in_clear' type='bool'>0</setting>
            <setting name='ssl' type='bool'>0</setting>
            <setting name='port' type='int'>6667</setting>
            <setting name='autodetect_utf8' type='bool'>0</setting>
            <setting name='sasl' type='bool'>0</setting>
            <setting name='encoding' type='string'>UTF-8</setting>
        </settings>
        <settings ui='gtk-gaim'>
            <setting name='auto-login' type='bool'>1</setting>
        </settings>
        <settings ui='gnt-purple'>
            <setting name='auto-login' type='bool'>1</setting>
        </settings>
        <current_error/>
    </account>
</account>
nicholas@dur:~$
```

Feel free to modify for your needs.  As an aside, finch is a console variant of pidgin which uses the same config files.